# Suspicious symbols on nginx config

Tags: nginx

I have the following nginx config, e.g.

```
server {
        listen   80;
        server_name example.com
        allow 127.0.0.0/8;
```

When I restart, it warn me:

```
Restarting nginx: nginx: [warn] server name "127.0.0.0/8" has suspicious 
symbols in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/xxx
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 147, accepted):

I guess you are missing the `;` at the end of the `server_name` directive so it interprets  the `allow` line as part of the server name.

```
server {
        listen   80;
        server_name example.com;
        allow 127.0.0.0/8;
```

Comment: I have been here before... I was just about to upvote your answer then I realized I already did! Thanks for a second time :-)

Comment: Thank you. I was missing the `;` at the end, and it was causing `404 Not Found
nginx` in my browser and `server name "/var/www/mysite" has suspicious symbols in /etc/nginx/sites-available/mysite.conf:8` in my `/var/log/nginx/error.log`.

Comment: Saved a life. I guess overlooked it because nginx doesn't see it as invalid syntax.

Comment: Typo'ing in a ':' rather a ';' will warn this as well.

Answer (score 8):

For me the cause of this error was having 'http://' in the server_name.

**i.e. I changed this:**

```
server {
    listen <Server name>:80;
    server_name <DNS name> http://localhost:28080;
    ...
```

**To this:**

```
server {
    listen <Server name>:80;
    server_name <DNS name> localhost:28080;
    ...
```

Answer (score 3):

A simple directive consists of the name and parameters separated by spaces and ends with a semicolon (;).

In your case server_name example.com semicolon (;) is missing.

```
server {
        listen   80;
        server_name example.com;
        allow 127.0.0.0/8;
```

Answer (score -2):

In my case error was in website url

```
server_name  http://testapp.com;
```

so I modified it this way

```
server_name  testapp.com;
```

and when I tried

> `sudo nginx -t`
> Outputnginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
> nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful

it worked for me