# nginx suspicious symbols warning in my nginx config file

Tags: nginx, django, gunicorn

My nginx configuration file is given below.

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name http://hg.rawdatatech.com;

  location / {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  }

  location /static/ {
    alias /home/home-garden/staticfiles/;
  }
}
```

When I run my Django application using this configuration I saw "suspicious symbol error" and connection refusing error nginx error log. Is there any wrong in my configuration?

Comment: First, your `server_name` is wrong. It should be plain domain name. Second, does your Django application even started?

Comment: Please do not paraphrase error messages quote them verbatim.

Comment: This helped me: https://serverfault.com/questions/447871/suspicious-symbols-on-nginx-config#comment1255249_447873

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `http://` from `server_name` config

New config will be something like this

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name hg.rawdatatech.com;

location / {
  proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
  proxy_set_header Host $host;
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
} 

location /static/ {
  alias /home/home-garden/staticfiles/;
}
}
```